# why can't the first container "see" the later containers

Tags: apache-zookeeper, docker-compose

I have a series of containers that are started by docker-compose. Specifically they are multiple zookeeper containers:

```
zk1:
    image: seven10/zookeeper:3.4.6
    container_name: zk1
    hostname: zk1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_ID=1
    net: ${MY_NETWORK_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /seven10/zk/zk1/data:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/data

  zk2:
    image: seven10/zookeeper:3.4.6
    container_name: zk2
    restart: always
    hostname: zk2
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
      - "2889:2888"
      - "3889:3888"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_ID=2
    net: ${MY_NETWORK_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /seven10/zk/zk2/data:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/data

  zk3:
    image: seven10/zookeeper:3.4.6
    container_name: zk3
    hostname: zk3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2183:2181"
      - "2890:2888"
      - "3890:3888"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_ID=3
    net: ${MY_NETWORK_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /seven10/zk/zk3/data:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/data
```

So when I go to start the containers, zk1 gives me this warning at the start:

```
WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=1]:QuorumCnxManager@382] - Cannot open channel to 3 at 
      election address zk3:3888
java.net.UnknownHostException: zk3
```

but then doesn't say anything else about zk3 after a couple of seconds.
However, zk1 gives the following error for zk2 continuously:

```
2016-02-18 15:28:57,384 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:Learner@233] - Unexpected exception, tries=0, connecting to zk2:2888
java.net.UnknownHostException: zk2
```

zk2 doesn't say ANYTHING ever about zk1, but briefly complains with the "cannot open channel" error for zk3.
zk3 doesn't every mention zk1 or zk2.

So the big problem is that zk1 can't find zk2 ever. It just spams the logs and refuses connections from kafka. Why is this so and how should I go about solving this problem?

My dev box is using docker version 1.9.1 and docker-compose version 1.5.1 on ubuntu 14.04 (Mint Rafello I think?), although the target environment will be ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: It seems like it only happens every other time I run it. When I delete all containers and data and restart it, it comes up fine. If I do that process again it doesn't work.
So there's that.

Comment: actually the reason it worked that one time was because zk1 was elected the leader. It fails when zk1 is not the leader.

Answer (score 0):

Does your host system know how to link zk1/2/3 to an IP address? If you're launching all three servers on the same node, you should use localhost as the host name (the server name should still be unique)